# Кнопки в диалоговом окне

Tags: jquery, javascript

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как подключать кнопки в диалоговое окно. Инфа [отсюда](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog). 
Кусок моего нерабочего кода

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js'></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".panel:even").addClass("alt");
        $(".panel .btn-delete").click(function(){
            $(function() {
                $( "#del" ).dialog();
            });

            $(this).parents(".panel").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
            return false;
        });

        $(".panel .edit").click(function(){
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            });
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Ok",
                    click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                }
            ]})
        });
    });
</script> 

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog</div>
```

Окно показывает с кнопкой.
1 Главная
Удалить | Редактировать
2 Левая
Удалить | Редактировать
3 Правая
Удалить | Редактировать
4 Средняя
Удалить | Редактировать
I'm in a dialog
Почему то надпись стоит всегда внизу текста, хотя она должна быть в окне.
И с кнопками так и не понял как делать.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот так](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-buttons).

**Обновлено.**
Если более подробно, то примерно так:

```
$(".panel .edit").dialog({
    buttons:{
        "OK": function(){},
        "not OK": function(){}
    }
});
```